# Написание названий медицинских препаратов

Tags: правила

Правильно ли, что названия медицинских препаратов нужно писать только с определяющим словом, например: препарат "Капотен", средство "Капотен", таблетки "Капотен", лекарство "Капотен". Например, такой вариант написания был признан грубой ошибкой: "Для снижения артериального давления врач назначил "Капотен". Спасибо.

Comment: @Linda, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Писать с родовым словом словом следует тогда, если речь идет, например, о торговой марке или, если важно подчеркнуть, что то или иное название представляет из себя препарат. В повседневной речи, если понятно, что речь идет именно о препарате, возможно написание и без родового слова. В приведенном вами предложении в названии препарата без родового слова("препарат") нет грубой ошибки, напротив, употребление с родовым словом может привести к плеоназму(излишние со смысловой точки зрения слова). Раз врач выписал, уже ясно, что препарат.  Ср.напр.: Врач выписал препарат "Левомицетин". В повседневной речи так никто не скажет.

Answer (score 3):

Да, это ошибка, потому что  в бытовом употреблении пишется без кавычек и со строчной буквы:Для снижения артериального давления врач назначил капотен. В крайнем случае - препарат (средство)"Капотен".
Грамота.ру пишет: "При употреблении в качестве торговой марки названия лекарственных средств следует писать с прописной буквы в кавычках: «Агри», «Инфлювак», «Афлубин», «Фервекс»,  а в бытовом употреблении – со строчной буквы без кавычек, например: выпить фервекс, принять виагру. Также пишутся со строчной буквы без кавычек некоторые названия лекарств, вошедшие в широкий обиход вследствие многолетнего употребления (валидол, анальгин, аспирин)".
http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters?rub=kav2

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я читала это правило в "Грамоте.ру" много раз, но там не сказано об определяющем слове, что меня собственно и интересует.

Comment: Там же написано: "...а в бытовом употреблении  -  со строчной буквы без кавычек, например: выпить **фервекс**, принять **виагру**". Обратите внимание: родовое слово отсутствует. Как я отметил выше, употребление с родовым словом в бытовой речи приводит к плеоназму.

Comment: Линда, я вас правильно понял: вы говорите об ошибке без родового?

Comment: Серж, я имела в виду, возможно ли писать так, как написано у меня, то есть название заключено в кавычки и начинается с прописной буквы, но без родового слова, а не про написание без родового слова, если название без кавычек и со строчной буквы начинается.

Comment: "При употреблении в качестве торговой марки названия лекарственных средств следует писать с прописной буквы в кавычках: «Агри», «Инфлювак», «Афлубин», «Фервекс»" - про родовое слово ничего не сказано.

Comment: Не написано, потому что и так ясно, что речь идет о препаратах. См.напр: "Справочник издателя и автора" А. Э. Мильчина, Л. К. Чельцовой указано, что «сокращение г. (город), как и полное слово, рекомендуется употреблять ограниченно, главным образом перед названиями городов, образованными от фамилий (г. Киров). Здесь практически действует та же ситуация. Слово"препарат" следует писать только тогда, когда надо указать, что речь идет именно о препарате.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы, но я так и не поняла, есть ошибка в моем предложении или нет. Я не филолог, поэтому и спросила. И непонятно, что такое бытовое употребление письменное, думаю, что в смс-сообщении другу или маме я бы не стала думать о таких тонкостях, как написать название лекарства.

Comment: Бытовое употребление, если не относится к официально-деловому стилю или научному.В документе на поставку лекарства указывается марка. В учебнике по фармацевтике - термин препарат "Капотен". А у вас бытовое употребление. Кто-то рассказывает кому-то о том, что врач назначил капотен. Это стилистика.Термины фармацевтики в бытовом общении употреблять нежелательно.Это ошибка.