# Название лекарства

Tags: орфография

Как правильно применять названия лекарств?

1. Я сегодня принял парацетамол.
2. У меня есть "Парацетамол".
3. Таблетка Парацетамола лежала на столе.

Answer (score 1):

Первое — парацет**а**мол.

Второе — при бытовом повествовании известные названия (анальгин, аспирин, цитрамон, валидол, нитроглицерин, нурофен, левомицетин...) пишутся без кавычек и со строчной буквы.

[Как правильно употреблять кавычки в собственных наименованиях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2)
[названия лекарств, медицинских препаратов]

*Миссис Элиза Макспадден, управляющая в замке, показала, что мистер Эрвилл накануне вечером жаловался на боли в груди и принял **две таблетки парацетамола*** (И. Бэнкс. Воронья дорога).

*Он открыл **пузырек с аспирином** зубами, выплюнул пробку в раковину, потом опрокинул пузырек и высыпал себе в рот с полдюжины таблеток* (С. Кинг. Темная половина).

Дополнительно:
[Написание названий медицинских препаратов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/43165/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 0):

На Грамоте это лекарство [есть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB&all=x), значит, правильно без кавычек и с маленькой буквы, как в первом вашем предложении.

Comment: Раз говорим "на сайте", то и "на Грамоте".

Comment: Да, конечно, я тоже говорю "на", просто ум за разум зашёл, видимо.))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Конечно, что **на** или что **то и**?! Первое - таки да, а вот втрое... **На стадионе**, но **в "Лужниках"**. **На пляже**, но **в "Серебряном Бору"**. - это просто первое, что в голову приходит, дело, понятно, не в Московских топонимах, а в непредсказуемости нормы выбора предлога в русском.

Comment: @behemothus: да нет, над логикой я особенно не задумывался, правильная она или нет (вижу, что вы правы, что предлог может меняться). Так что "конечно" только насчёт того, что в данном случае **надо** было таки исправить на "на". :)